# Regex to match words with special characters at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regexp pattern below which works fine for my purpose except for keywords followed by special characters such as: C#

```
var pattern = new RegExp("(?<!\w)(" + str.join("|") + ")\\b(?!-)", "gi");
```

So how can I also detect keywords such as C#?

Comment: Could you add an example of what `str.join("|")` could be ?

Comment: It's to join an array with keywords such as: 
["excel",".net","technology-based","software & framework","C#"];

Comment: Change `\\b(?!-)` into `(?![\w-])`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this pattern with the Jquery highlight-text-inside-a-textarea plugin. So with your pattern (?![\w-]) C# gets highlighted now, but another problem occurs which I didn't have before i.e. the keyword excel gets highlight in the keywords excellent.

Comment: I haven't this behaviour, https://regex101.com/r/brG5go/1

Comment: here is the code with your change, is there anything else I need to change? RegExp("(?<!\w)(" + str.join("|") + ")(?![\w-])", "gi");